# Discord bot, what a bug in the buttons embed code

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have problem with my discord bot. My sql database returns 20 pages as a result and I would like to add page scroll buttons (next, previous) to the embed. After modifying the code, the application is not responding, no errors in the console. Can someone help what I'm doing wrong?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const mysql = require("mysql");

require('dotenv').config();
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xxx',
  user: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  database: 'xxx'
});

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('Try schematics'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const page = parseInt(interaction.options.getNumber('page')) || 1;
    const itemsPerPage = 10;

    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM schematics ORDER BY schema ASC`, (err, rows2) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', err);
        return interaction.reply('Error mysql.');
      }

      if (rows2.length === 0) {
        const embedAuto = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor('Red')
          .setDescription('<:icons_Wrong:1126116080990048256> Nothing schematics!');
        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embedAuto] });
      }

      const totalItems = rows2.length;
      const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / itemsPerPage);
      const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
      const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
      const bronLista = rows2.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(bron => {
        return `<:icons_info:1125845588945145976> Name: **${bron.schema}**\nKind: ${bron.kind}`;
      }).join('\n\n');

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('Orange')
        .setTitle('Schematic:')
        .setDescription(`<:icons_exclamation:1126569449982529557> Available schematics: **${totalItems}**\n\n ${bronLista}`)
        .setFooter({ text: `User: ${interaction.user.tag} | Page ${page}/${totalPages}`, iconURL: interaction.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
        .setTimestamp();

      const prevButton = new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('prev_page')
        .setLabel('Previous')
        .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        .setDisabled(page === 1);

      const nextButton = new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('next_page')
        .setLabel('Next')
        .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        .setDisabled(page === totalPages);

      const actionRow = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(prevButton, nextButton);

      interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow] });


      const filter = i => i.customId === 'prev_page' || i.customId === 'next_page';
      const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

      collector.on('collect', async i => {
        if (i.customId === 'prev_page') {
          page--;
        } else if (i.customId === 'next_page') {
          page++;
        }

        const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
        const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
        const bronLista = rows2.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(bron => {
          return `<:icons_info:1125845588945145976> Name: **${bron.schema}**\nKind: ${bron.kind}`;
        }).join('\n\n');

        embed.setDescription(`<:icons_exclamation:1126569449982529557> Available schematics: **${totalItems}**\n\n ${bronLista}`);
        embed.setFooter({ text: `User: ${interaction.user.tag} | Page ${page}/${totalPages}`, iconURL: interaction.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }) });

        await i.update({ embeds: [embed] });
      });

      collector.on('end', collected => {
        actionRow.setDisabled(true);
        interaction.editReply({ components: [actionRow] });
      });
    });
  }
};
```

When I use a normal page reference the code works

Answer (score 0):

If you use discord.js v14, Try change `MessageActionRow` to `ActionRowBuilder` and `MessageButton` to `ButtonBuilder`, use `ButtonStyle` to get button color style:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require("discord.js");
```

```js
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('Orange')
        .setTitle('Schematic:')
        .setDescription(`<:icons_exclamation:1126569449982529557> Available schematics: **${totalItems}**\n\n ${bronLista}`)
        .setFooter({ text: `User: ${interaction.user.tag} | Page ${page}/${totalPages}`, iconURL: interaction.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
        .setTimestamp();

      const prevButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('prev_page')
        .setLabel('Previous')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setDisabled(page === 1);

      const nextButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('next_page')
        .setLabel('Next')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setDisabled(page === totalPages);

      const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(prevButton, nextButton);
```

And check your discord.js version

[discord.js docs](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs)

[discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide)